# Matter.js How to make bodies (circles) bounce endlessly (perfect elasticity) in a box with 0 gravity

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am specifically looking for body options that would work when the world gravity (both x and y) is 0.
My current body options are as follows:

```
physics: {
    frictionAir: 0,
    friction: 0,
    frictionStatic: 0,
    inertia: Infinity,
    restitution: 1,
    label: 'circle'+Date.now()+Math.random(),
    collisionFilter: {
      mask: 0x001
    },
},
```

Tried various combinations, including continuously applying setVelocity and/or applyForce but these don't work as expected. I would expect that applying setVelocity once only would make all the bodies keep moving forever. So in my `update` function I do something like this:

```
        if(!this.setInMotion){
            Matter.Body.setVelocity(myBody, 
                {x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2, 
                y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2})
            this.setInMotion = true
        }
```

but the bodies simply move (slowly) to sides of the box (which is made of static rectangles) and either slide along them to corners thereof, or stop completely without bouncing at all.
Setting the setAngularVelocity does make things bounce, but then the directions and velocities after each collision become not what's expected.

Thank you for your time.

Jared

Comment: Hi Jared - I'm also interested in this and was wondering if you have had any luck?

Comment: Still working on it :)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
    if(!this.setInMotion){
        Matter.Body.setVelocity(myBody, 
            {x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2, 
            y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2})
        this.setInMotion = true
    }
```

with

```
if (!this.setInMotion) {
    this.setInMotion = true
    var vx = 0.001 * (Math.random() - 0.5)
    var vy = 0.001 * (Math.random() - 0.5)
    Matter.Engine._bodiesApplyGravity([myBody], { x: vx, y: vy })
}
```

this hack will use applyGravity inner matterjs engine function to properly apply push motion in direction vx, vy when world.gravity is set to 0

Regards, Jacek

Comment: I understand why this might work (i.e. look right) but I can't figure out where the update function goes... Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set frictionStatic to **1**

```
physics: {
    frictionAir: 0,
    friction: 0,
    frictionStatic: 1,
    inertia: Infinity,
    restitution: 1,
    label: 'circle'+Date.now()+Math.random(),
    collisionFilter: {
       mask: 0x001
    },
},
```

Comment: Does not work. To be honest, I cannot see why this solution would work. Maybe it helps somewhat if the gravity is non-zero. Heck, if the y gravity is 1 all seems to bounce endlessly, but I've got to have this behaviour with x and y gravity 0 (I noticed I wasn't clear on this in my question - correcting now).

Answer (score 0):

> but the bodies simply move (slowly) to sides of the box (which is made
> of static rectangles) and either slide along them to corners thereof,
> or stop completely without bouncing at all

Late to the party, but this is resolved by restingThresh in matterjs config to a value lower than the default (4). In my case (a breakout game), setting this to 0.1 did the job for me

See the following issue:
https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/394